# Indentations Gone Amiss with Loops

Tags: python, indentation

I am trying to run this program but my indentations are completely wrong. I'm not exactly sure what they should be:

```
import os.path

count = 1

for i in range(15):
fname = "/tmp/agent-" + str(count)+".txt"
if os.path.isfile(fname):
with open(fname, 'r') as content_file:
content = content_file.read()
print(content.rstrip())
count += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess:

```
import os.path

count = 1

for i in range(15):
    fname = "/tmp/agent-" + str(count)+".txt"
    if os.path.isfile(fname):
        with open(fname, 'r') as content_file:
            content = content_file.read()
            print(content.rstrip())
    count += 1 # maybe, maybe not
```

Comment: Variable `content` will live past the `with` block, so you can de-dent the `print()` invocation one level without ill effect.